# I need to trasform the types of vector and individuate NA values

Tags: r

Goodmornig, I built a dataframe with rbind(). I have all colums defined as characters. My issue is that I don't know how trasform these colums in other types (numeric, factors,....) and also I need to individuate the NA inside the dataframe.

The datasets that composed the rbind dataframe are file.xlsx. I try to use write.table, read.table, read_excel but I haven't solved the problem.

Comment: Are you reading in an .xlsx file ie, loading an excel file into R, or trying to build a dataframe using `rbind()`?
For Excel files (.xlsx) I'd recommend using the `readxl` package.

If it is creating a dataframe, then I suspect that you might have NAs coded as characters and not "real" NAs which then converts the entire column to character.

Can you provide an example of what code you are running?

Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) for help in creating a reproducible example.